# Solve $(\cos^2{x}+y \sin{2x})\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}+y^2=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve
$$(\cos^2{x}+y \sin{2x}) \frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}+y^2=0$$
Please help me to solve this. It is not possible for me to separate.
Attempt : If $M=\cos^2{x}+y \sin{2x}, N=y^2$ then $M_y=\sin{2x}, N_x=0$ are not equal.

Comment: Then you might want to try to find an integrating factor to multiply the equation by that puts the problem in exact form.

Comment: @mattos Yes. What will be the IF.

Comment: Multiply through your equation by $\mu(x,y)$ and then compute $M_{y}, N_{x}$ from the expressions $M = \mu(\cos^{2}(x)+y\sin(2x))$ and $N = \mu y^{2}$. The condition $M_{y} = N_{x}$ generates a linear, first order PDE in $\mu$ to solve which yields the form of the integrating factor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(\cos^2{x}+y \sin{2x}) \frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}+y^2=0$$
Divide by $\cos^2 x$ (The DE becomes exact):
$$(1+2y \tan x) y'+\dfrac {y^2}{\cos^2 x}=0$$
$$y'+\color {red}{2yy' \tan x +\dfrac {y^2}{\cos^2 x}}=0$$
$$y'+\color{red}{(y^2\tan x)'}=0$$
Integrate.
$$y+y^2\tan x=C$$

Comment: $(y^2\tan x)'$ is not clear

Comment: Differentiate it will be more clear @user1942348  it gives $$2yy'\tan x + y^2/\cos^2x $$ Exactly what you have in the line before that.

Comment: I added some lines Hope it"s clear now @user1942348 The DE is exact after you divide by $\cos^2 x$